# Какой метод вызывать после возобновления фрагмента?

Tags: android

Я из фрагмента запускаю новое активити, потом закрываю его и попадаю опять в свой фрагмент. Какой метод мне использовать, после закрытия активити во фрагменте?(onStart? onResume?)

Comment: Использовать для чего?

Answer (score 2):

*Список дополнительных методов жизненного цикла фрагментов, которых нет у активности:*

**onAttach(Activity)**
Вызывается, когда фрагмент связывается с активностью. С этого момента мы можем получить ссылку на активность через метод getActivity()

**onCreate()**
В этом методе можно сделать работу, не связанную с интерфейсом. Например, подготовить адаптер.

**onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle)**
Вызывается для создания компонентов внутри фрагмента

**onActivityCreated(Bundle)**
Вызывается, когда отработает метод активности onCreate(), а значит фрагмент может обратиться к компонентам активности

**onDestroyView()**
Вызывается, когда набор компонентов удаляется из фрагмента

**onDetach()**
Вызывается, когда фрагмент отвязывается от активности
Одноимённые с методами активности методы фрагментов выполняют аналогичные функции.

К примеру, метод **onResume()** вызывается, когда фрагмент вновь становится видимым.

Метод **onStart()** вызывается, когда фрагмент становится видимым после запуска такого же метода в родительской активности.

Фрагмент всегда связан с активностью. Отдельно фрагмент от активности существовать не может.

Если активность останавливается, то её фрагменты также останавливаются. Если активность уничтожается, то её фрагменты также уничтожаются.

Метод **onCreateView(**) вызывается один раз, когда фрагмент должен загрузить на экран свой интерфейс. В этом методе вы можете "надуть" (inflate) разметку фрагмента через метод inflate() объекта Inflater, который задан в параметре метода. В фрагментах без интерфейса вы можете пропустить надувание.

Метод **onActivityCreated()** вызывается после метода **onCreateView()**, когда создаётся активность-хозяйка для фрагмента. Здесь можно объявить объекты, необходимые для Context.

Фрагменты не являются подклассами Context, вам следует использовать метод **getActivity()**, чтобы получить родительскую активность.